# Read csv file including the column names as values

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a csv file like this:

```
1,2,3
4,5,6
7,8,9
```

I did `x = pd.read_csv({csv_filename})` and when I do `x.head()`, I only see:

```
4,5,6
7,8,9
```

where `1,2,3` are set as column names.

I would like to see:

```
1,2,3
4,5,6
7,8,9
```

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Comment: `header=None`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the `header` property to `None`, because the *default* value is `infer`(column names are inferred from the first line of the file).

```
x = pd.read_csv(csv_filename, header=None)
```